# Remove/Add "defaultvaluesql" of a column using Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Here I have a migration of CodeFirst using EF6

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.MyTable",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Date = c.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETUTCDATE()"),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
}
```

But we found that the `Date` could not be customized at insert. So we need a migration to delete the `defaultValueSql` parameter on `Date` column.

I've tried using `AlterColumn` without `defaultValueSql` parameter,

```
public override void Up()
{
    AlterColumn("dbo.MyTable", "Date", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false));
}

public override void Down()
{
    AlterColumn("dbo.MyTable", "Date", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETUTCDATE()"));
}
```

it works neither for inserting and updating the `Date`, nor to the definition of table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] (
    [Id] INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Date]        DATETIME        DEFAULT (getutcdate()) NOT NULL,
);
```

Anyone has run into this situation, please ?

Comment: Creating a constructor with datatime as parameter makes insert working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, in the database, there was a `Constraint` created for the `defaultValueSql`, and I think this parameter works by the **sys** table, rather than `MyTable`, which results in ineffective of my `AlterColumn`.

Eventually, I created some original SQL commands for my purpose like following:

```
public override void Up()
{
    Sql(@"
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @sql = N'alter table [EffectiveDonations] drop constraint ['+d.name+N']'
    FROM sys.default_constraints
    WHERE d.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'MyTable')
    AND col_name(parent_object_id, parent_column_id) = N'Date'
    EXEC (@sql)
    ");
    Sql("PRINT 'Information: delete [defaultvaluesql]';");
}

public override void Down()
{
    Sql(@"ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD DEFAULT getutcdate() FOR [Date]");
    Sql("PRINT 'Information: create [defaultvaluesql] for column [Date] of table [MyTable]';");
}
```

Share to hope this could be help to others.

Answer (score 1):

Try it in two stages:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AlterColumn("dbo.MyTable", "Date", c => c.DateTime(nullable: true,
                                                       defaultValue: "NULL"));
    AlterColumn("dbo.MyTable", "Date", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false));
}
```

Comment: It added `CONSTRAINT [DF_dbo.EffectiveDonations_Date] DEFAULT (NULL)` if we looked into the definition of tabel. I have added some test data in Seed() where it occurs the errors _Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Date', table 'MyTable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails._